Discord.Net ConnectAsync() runs into timeout
I am writing a discord bot and I want to add a feature but I'm having troubles with it.
When the user connects to a specific channel the bot will move the user to another channel.
The bot should also connect to this channel, but I can't seem to get async to work.
A minimal version of my code:
private async Task UserVoiceUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
{
    var guild = (user as SocketGuildUser)?.Guild;
    
    if (guild == null) {return;}
    
    var guildUser = guild.GetUser(user.Id);
    
    if (guildUser == null) {return;}
    
    var audioVoiceChannel = guild.GetVoiceChannel(guildUser.VoiceChannel.Id);
    
    if (audioVoiceChannel == null) {return;}
    
    var audioClient = await audioVoiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
    
    // the rest of the code
}

I also tried running a Task:
private async Task UserVoiceUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
{
    var guild = (user as SocketGuildUser)?.Guild;
    
    if (guild == null) {return;}
    
    var guildUser = guild.GetUser(user.Id);
    
    if (guildUser == null) {return;}
    
    var audioVoiceChannel = guild.GetVoiceChannel(guildUser.VoiceChannel.Id);
    
    if (audioVoiceChannel == null) {return;}
    
    var x = Task.Run(async () => {
    
        var audioClient = await audioVoiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
        
        // rest of the code
    
    });
}

To dig further into the issue I created a small command that makes the bot connect to a specified voicechannel (I am still using text commands for now):
if (ulong.TryParse(args[1], out channelId))
{
    var guild = (user as SocketGuildUser)?.Guild;
    var voiceChannel = guild.GetVoiceChannel(channelId);
    var audioClient = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
}

When using async, I run into a timeout. When not using async it seems to connect normally.
I'd need the async though, since I want to create a PCMStream.
I saw the other thread on stackoverflow, that's why I tried the task, but it didn't work for me.
Would be nice if somebody could help me out with this one.
Thanks!
EDIT:
I moved the code into a seperate Task:
private async Task ConnectToVoiceChannel(IVoiceChannel channel)
{
    if (channel == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    IAudioClient client = null;

    try
    {
        client = await channel.ConnectAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("success");
    }
    
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("error\r\n" + ex.Message); }

    if (client != null)
    {
        await client.StopAsync();
    }
}

but this is the result:
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()

